# How to create email / SMS activity using Apex

Tags: apex, activity

When sending an email, it is possible to set:

```
mail.setSaveAsActivity(true);
```

Which creates an Email record in the activity time line.

How would I create one of these using code?

And what other types are available? i.e. SMS?

Comment: Ask your AE about adding Einstein Activity Capture to your account.  It does all of the email/event sync'ing for you (and it will look much nicer)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Records shown as Activities in Salesforce are one of three kinds of sObject:

- `Task` (Log a Call, follow-up Tasks)
- `Event` (calendar events)
- `EmailMessage` + `Task` (emails)

Additionally, the `Task` object has a `TaskSubtype` field, whose value causes Lightning's Activity timeline to display the task as a call, a task, an email, or a list email, with different visual presentation for each subtype. Note that the `TaskSubtype` field is "creatable", but not "updateable" - you can populate it only upon insert. (The `Event` object has an `EventSubtype` field, but it's not used).

So, if all you wish to do is show an entry in the Lightning Activity timeline that is presented as an email, you need simply to insert a Task whose `TaskSubtype` field is `'Email'`:

```
insert new Task(
    Subject = 'Subject: Test email....', 
    WhoId = myContact.Id, 
    WhatId = myOpportunity.Id,
    TaskSubtype = 'Email',
    ActivityDate = Date.today(),
    ...
);
```

There is no `TaskSubtype` or sObject for SMS messages, and it's not possible to customize the visual presentation of the Lightning activity timeline. You can, of course, represent them as `Task` records, and pick which of the four allowed subtypes most fits what you want your users to see and filter by.

Comment: I am creating a task as suggested `insert new Task(
            Subject = 'SMS Reminder', 
            Description = messageBody,
            WhoId = whoId,
            WhatId = whatId,
            Priority = 'Normal',
            Status = 'Closed',
            TaskSubtype = 'Email',
            ActivityDate = Date.today());`

Yet it is not appearing in the activity timeline?

Comment: Stupid question, but have you refreshed the page? Lightning doesn't auto-detect new Tasks unless the publisher itself creates them. It should appear on the pages of the Who and What records, if the insert itself succeeded.

Comment: Yup. It is not appearing on the timeline for the whoId or whatId.

Comment: My bad. I was setting the `whoId` to an account ID rather than the `PersonContactId`

Comment: How would I set both the date and time on the Task, such that it appears in the correct place in the timeline? currently it is being added for the date only, therefore recent emails appear above it, even if my new record is more recent.

Comment: Tasks don't have a time associated with them. `ActivityDate` is a Date field, rather than DateTime. I don't know all of the permutations of the sorting rules used by the Activity timeline offhand.

Answer (score 3):

```
Task ts = new Task();
ts.Subject = 'test1';
ts.TaskSubtype = 'Email';
ts.ActivityDate = Date.today();
ts.Description =  'emailtest1';
ts.WhatID      =  AccountID;
ts.WhoID       =  ContactID;
ts.Status = 'Completed';
insert ts;
```

I use this code for receive email so i can save received email to Activity history.